# How to transfer (copy) NFTs from Rarible to OpenSea

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

I've posted 1000 NFT images on Rarible via 'lazy minting'. All images go to a public folder (collection) by default on Rarible, if you don't pay. Now I would like to show (copy) this set of images also on OpenSea. How can I do that?
What if I would like to move my NFT images from the Rarible public repository to a custom collection on Rarible? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Only Rarible allows the lazy-minting option you can't directly import from Rarible to Opensea unless you have deployed on-chain.

Lazy-minting on Rarible works off-chain when a user buys your NFT he pays the gas fees then it mints on-chain. Also you can't create a custom collection without Smart Contract.

You can import Rarible-Opensea using ERC-721 or ERC-1155 contract - https://opensea.io/get-listed

Also, how did you post 1000 images to Rarible? Using Macro recorder?

Comment: No. I used a NodeJS script.

Comment: Oh fine then so try to create an ERC-1155 contract it allows you to mint 500 NFT Tokens in one transaction once it's deployed go to the Etherscan verify your contract and then select Write Contract to mint new NFT tokens.